# How to Get the content inside parenthesis using Regex C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string and i need to get the content inside the string.

I have tried the following Regex  . But it comes with the outer paranthesis.

Input string :

```
           Test (1001,Sunday)
```

Regex Pattern

```
          Regex : (([^,]+),([^,)]+)) 
          Output : (1001
```

But I require output like the following

```
         match[0]=1001 , match[1] = sunday.
```

I also tried the following patterns but ended up with build warnings.

```
          (Test \(([^)]+)\)) :
```

Due to escape sequence i was not able to build it without warnings.

The above Regex works fine for me but i get compilation warnings

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is your input string, the pattern you've tried, the code you've tried, and explanation text. Can you look through the editor help and format your post to make it more clear?

Comment: I have updated the question and the description. Kindly have a  look.

Comment: With this one example input, I'm not sure what you expect other valid and invalid inputs to be. Can you describe a valid format?

Comment: My input will be saved in an array like this as string [0] Test(1001,Sunday) , [1] Test(1002,Monday) ... etc  .. is there any way to get only the content inside the parenthesis ( Need the content )

Comment: `string final = input.Substring(input.IndexOf("(") + 1, input.LastIndexOf(")") - input.IndexOf("(") - 1);` something along those lines using `IndexOf`. More than one way of doing this, just an alternative; `linq` would also suffice as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this all with Regex, just match the parenthesis section.

```
\((\S+?),(\S+?)\)
```

Then group 1 will be "1001" and group 2 will be "Sunday".

```
var input = "Test (1001,Sunday)";
var pattern = new Regex(@"\((\S+?),(\S+?)\)");
var match = pattern.Match(input);

Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

In this pattern I'm using `\S`, which is "any non-whitespace character". You can change this as need be. For example, if you know that the first group is always going to be digits, change to `\d`.

---

Another way of doing this that doesn't involve Regex (thanks [Trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71327371/how-to-get-the-content-inside-parenthesis-using-regex-c/71327710#comment126078186_71327371) for the idea), it to search for the only `(` and `)` characters, substring, and split by commas.

```
var input = "Test (1001,Sunday)";
var start = input.IndexOf('(') + 1; // +1 to avoid including "("
var end = input.LastIndexOf(')');
var data = input[start..end];
var segments = data.Split(',');

foreach (var segment in segments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the range struct here, perfect usage, I don't see this utilized often!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `(([^,]+),([^,)]+))` has 3 capture groups, where group 2 for example matches any character except a comma `[^,]+`.

That negated character class will also match the opening `(`

What you might do is use 2 capture groups instead, exclude the parenthesis as well, and also match the opening and closing parenthesis in the example string.

```
\(([^,()]+),([^,()]+)\)
```

See a [.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%5b%5e%2c%28%29%5d%2b%29%2c%28%5b%5e%2c%28%29%5d%2b%29%5c%29&i=%281001%2cSunday%29) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/audS4P).

---

If there can be more than 2 values between the parenthesis,
you can make use of a capture group with the same name, and the [Group.Captures Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-6.0).

```
\((?<val>[^,()]+)(?:,(?<val>[^,()]+))*\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?<val>[^,()]+)` Group `val`, match 1 or more occurrences of any char except `,` `(` `)`
- `(?:` Non capture group to capture as a whole

  - `,` Match literally
  - `(?<val>[^,()]+)` Again group val with the same pattern
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to also allow a single value
- `\)` Match `)`

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%2c%28%29%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%2c%28%3f%3cval%3e%5b%5e%2c%28%29%5d%2b%29%29*%5c%29&i=Test+%281001%2cSunday%29) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CJ5OCs).

```
var pattern = @"\((?<val>[^,()]+)(?:,(?<val>[^,()]+))*\)";
var str = "Test (1001,Sunday)";
var strings = Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups["val"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value);

foreach (String s in strings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Output

```
1001
Sunday
```

Comment: But i get build warnings . Without warnings i need to compile it . It comes because of '\'

Comment: @SAR What do you mean by build warnings? What are you building? Do you get errors compiling the C# code? Did you see the example code?

Answer (score -1):

If your string is always of the pattern

```
a(b,c)
```

And you want b and c in different variables it might be simplest to just split on multiple delimiters:

```
var input = "Test(1001,sunday)";
var bits = input.Split('(',')',',');
```

Now your "1001" is in `bits[1]` and "sunday" is in `bits[2]`

---

You mentioned that your input is an an array:

```
var input = new []{
  "Test(1001,sunday)",
  "Test(1002,monday)"
};
```

So you could:

```
var r = input.Select(i => {
  var bits = i.Split('(',')',',');
  return new { Num = bits[1], Day = bits[2] };
});
```

This would produce an enumeration of anonymous types objects where each one has your requested data in its Num/Day properties

```
foreach(var a in r)
  Console.Write($"Num is {a.Num} and Day is {a.Day}");
```